# How to bind click event to element, after it has been unbinded?

Tags: jquery, button, navigation, bind, href

I'm relatively new to jquery as well as in all other forms of web programing.

I am trying to build main navigation. Menu that dynamically loads external pages into single div, with some simple transition effects.

So far everything is working well, except that button with .current class remains inactive even when other items are clicked.

Id like to see that active button is clickable again, after other buttons being clicked.
So there is only one inactive item with .current class at the time.

i tried with .bind .unbind, .on .off, addAttr ...  without result.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#pageWraper').css({'display':'none'}).slideDown('fast');

    $("a.menuLink").on("click", function(event) {
        var pageLink = $(this).attr('href');

        event.preventDefault();
         $(".currentPage").fadeOut('slow', function(){
             $("#pageWraper").load(pageLink);
         });

         $('#navigationWraper li a').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current').removeAttr('href').unbind('click');
    });
});
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gundra/GW8mb/1/

Hope there is a simple solution for this,
Thanks

Comment: Why unbind the click? Just check for the current class before doing anything in your click handler http://jsfiddle.net/GW8mb/4/

Comment: Yeah that's the best way I think, what @Huangism said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to unbind, you just need to check for the `current` class before doing anything

http://jsfiddle.net/GW8mb/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#pageWraper').css({
        'display': 'none'
    }).slideDown('fast');

    $("a.menuLink").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('current')) {
            var pageLink = $this.attr('href');

            $(".currentPage").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $("#pageWraper").load(pageLink);
            });

            $('#navigationWraper li a').removeClass('current');
            $this.addClass('current');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?  just highlight the active menu item?

http://jsfiddle.net/GW8mb/3/

From there just use the pageLink var to load in whatever content into the container div.

```
$('#navigationWraper li a').removeClass('current');
     $(this).addClass('current');
```

Comment: Also, if you're trying to prevent reloading the page if the user clicks on the active link, just check to see if the clicked link has the `current` class applied, if so, do nothing.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); will prevent the page reloading, stops the tags default action in this case a link.

Comment: Yes Zack, thats excatly wath i want, prevent reloading the page. Maybe i should go for some if else :).  thanks

Comment: user1572796 -  event.preventDefault();  didnt help me anyhow, did i do something wrong ?

Comment: The page won't reload with `preventDefault()` but the `#pageWrapper` will still load the new page each time since that loading is done in js